# java.io.FileNotFoundException gradle.properties (Operation not permitted)

Tags: android, macos, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I am installing a ionic Angular & Cordova on new Mac book pro, testing it with ionic starter templates before migrating my project from my old Mac book pro.

I am currently using this installation guides :

https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/android

https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/android.

Everything works fine with iOS. 
I am actually facing the following error while trying to test with android :

```
    ionic cordova run android -l
```

I get the following error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/ [...] /super/platforms/android/gradle.properties (Operation not permitted)
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/6.1.1/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 1

Beside trying to reinstall several elements and check installation guides, I also tried to review and allow read & write permissions for the entire project.

If anyone has a lead or a solution it would be great.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is my setup

```
Ionic:
   Ionic CLI                     : 6.0.1 (/Users/****/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.6
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.20
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.20
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.20
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1
```

Cordova:
   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:
   cordova-res : 0.9.0
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:
   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/****/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.10.0
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v12.14.1 (/Users/****/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.13.4
   OS                : macOS Catalina
   Xcode             : Xcode 11.3.1 Build version 11C504

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-01-24 22:30:24 UTC
Revision:     a8c3750babb99d1894378073499d6716a1a1fa5d

Kotlin:       1.3.61
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_241 (Oracle Corporation 25.241-b07)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.3 x86_64
```

```
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
```

The gradle.properties file has the following content:

```
    org.gradle.daemon=true
    org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
    android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
    cdvMinSdkVersion=19
```

Comment: This is now solved. Not sure which one of the following has been the master key but I did reinstalled once more the JDK8  and select the Android SDK Build tools 19.1.0 into the Android studio SDK manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar happened to me after updating Android Studio. I have restarted my Mac and the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Run Android Studio as an Administrator

```
sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
```

Comment: Unless absolutely required, running an application as root is rarely a good idea.